# Oracle DB. how to compress BLOB images columns preserving image type

Tags: oracle, image, compression, blob

I wish to extract, compress and upload some images stored into a BLOB DB column. I tried this approach

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CompressImg (p_id in varchar2) as
v_blob_column blob;
 begin  

  FOR crs IN (SELECT id_img, img FROM  TabImages where id = p_id) 
  LOOP
  v_blob_column := utl_compress.lz_compress(crs.img);
  insert into TabCompressedImages(id, id_img, img) values(p_id, crs.id_img,v_blob_column);
  END LOOP;

end CompressImg;
/
```

this works, but compressed blobs are corrupted! By a simple extension check

SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(IMG,2,1) FROM ....

it turns out that original blob files (TabImages.img) return 'FFD8' string (ie: jpg files), while compressed ones (TabCompressedImages.img) return '1F8B'.
so, it looks like compression process have corrupted the blob files. how can I compress them preserving the original format? thanks

Comment: The original format would be retained when you decompress though, right? The format of your BLOB is now zip not jpeg, so what it's showing you doesn't seem unreasonable? If you have a suitable version and licence, maybe look at [the built-in Advanced LOB Compression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adlob/using-oracle-LOBs-storage.html#GUID-F74C5330-91F7-4C0E-BB83-6FAA8D0FCCBE), which is transparent. Otherwise, I guess you could store the file type (MIME type?) as a separate column value.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a very simplified example where compressing a number could be represented by adding 5 to it. If you have a value, 42, and compress it and store it in the database then you will store 47 and then when you read the value from the database you will see that compressed value, 47, and not the original value, 42.

If you want to see the original value then you have to decompress the compressed value by reversing the process; in this simple example, decompression would be subtracting 5 from the number so all we need to is decompress the value and we are back to the original.

When you want to get the compressed image then either:

1. Read the compressed image and send the compressed image to the user as-is and inform the user of how to decompress the value and let the user decompress it on the client-side; or
2. Read the compressed image, decompress it and then send the decompressed image to the user.

So for the simplified example, you have the choice of either:

- sending the user the value 47 and telling them that they will have to decompress it when they receive it and telling them how to decompress the value (i.e. subtract 5); or
- you can subtract 5 and send the original value 42 and then the receiving user does not need to know anything about how you stored the value.

> it looks like compression process have corrupted the blob files.

The files have not been corrupted, they have been compressed (you told the database to perform the compression).

> how can I compress them preserving the original format?

You cannot, file formats and compression do not work like that. Compression takes the data in the file and rewrites it in a more compact format but then, in most cases<sup>1</sup>, the compressed data is no longer immediately recognisable as the original file format (until you decompress it and restore the original file).

If you want to see the image from the compressed file then reverse the compression process and decompress it using [`UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_UNCOMPRESS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_COMPRESS.html#GUID-871A2DE4-7C69-431D-920C-FD3450DDB685).

*<sup>1</sup> There are image file formats (such as PNG, JPEG or TIFF) with built-in compression where you can adjust the level of compression and could re-save an image with a lower compression level with a higher compression level and it would still be an image but you are not compressing the images using that (and I do not know of any built-in Oracle functions that would support such image manipulations); you are using LZ compression which will rewrite the file into a different format.*